# Handling multiple requests with same body - REST API

Tags: rest, queue, microservices, rate-limiting

Let's say I have a micro service which just registers a user into the database and we expose it to our client. I want to understand what's the better way of handling the following scenario,

1. What if the user sends multiple requests in parallel(say 10 requests within the 1 second) with same request body. Should I keep the requests in a queue and register for the very first user and deny all the other 9 requests, or should I classify each request and compare whichever having similar request body and if any of them has different request body shall be picked up one each and rest are rejected? or What's the best thing I can do to handle this scenario?
2. One more thing I would like to understand, is it recommended to have rate-limiting (say n requests per minute) on a global API level or micro-service level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Up to you. 2. Up to the service you're using.

Comment: @Enigmativity So I could use maybe a map from `ip` to `req-body` (specific controller level) and filter out similar requests and reject them happily considering them as some sort of bombarding attack? Whereas the cached map expires after `x` duration

Comment: You seem to have a better idea about your scenario than us. We can only give you our opinion of the little that we know. It's unlikely that we'll be able to give you any practical answer. You should try whatever you think and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use an idempotent call. Instead of exposing an endpoint like this :

```
POST /users + payload
```

Expose an endpoint like this :

```
PUT /user/ID + payload
```

You let the caller generate the id, and you ask for an UUID. With UUID, no matter who generates it. This way, if caller invokes your endpoint multiple times, the first time you will create the user, the following times you will juste update the user with the same payload, which means you'll do nothing. At least you won't generate duplicates.

It's always a good practice to protect your services with rate-limiting. You have to set it at API level. If you define it at microservice level, you will authorize N times the rate if you have N instances, because you will ditribute the requests.